# covert time Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to convert time to Indian Time zone, I put my time in Gmt or in CET or in CST( as i like in my radio bouton)and it should convert to the IST time.
I use google apps script and UI for my project.

thank you for help

Comment: Please share some code and the specific problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

[formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatDate) should let you do the necessary timezone conversion.

Comment: thank u for your response , i try with Utilities.formatDate but it doesn't work can u show me how exactly please :)

Comment: Well, might be better if you include some of the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I like to work with date in this way. I hope it help you:

```
var fechaYYMMDD = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-03", "yyMMdd");
var horasHHMMSS = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-03", "HHmmss");

var fechaYHora =  fechaYYMMDD + "_" + horasHHMMSS;
```